# Newton's Method in C++

Tags: c++, newtons-method, cmath

I am trying to translate f(x) = x − e<sup>-(x<sup>2</sup>)</sup> in c++ source code but I keep getting errors. I have tried :

```
double f(double x)
{
    exp = pow(-x, 2);
    double result = x - exp;
    return x;

};
```

Any insight?
If it helps, I am using Code::Blocks

Comment: When you say `e^(-x2)`, do you mean `e^(-x*2)` or do you mean `e^((-x)^2)`?

Comment: You may want to rename your `exp` variable, [`std::exp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp)

Comment: I mean  e^((-x)^2)

Comment: I doubt that. (-x)^2 == x^2. Surely you mean -(x^2)

Comment: That's not Newton's Method. With Newton's method you make a linear estimate at your current x, then try a prospective root value of `x_next = x - f(x)/(derivative_of_f(x))`.

Comment: @einpoklum. The question does not actually refer to the title at all. Perhaps he also has an f_prime(x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>
double f(double x)
{
    return x - exp(-(x*x));
}
```

Comment: @abelenky: He probably copied OP's code first. But - you could just fix it. Which is what I've just done.

Comment: Thanks for the green stamp. I am saving up for that toaster oven.